# Passport-facebook access req object from within callback function

Tags: node.js, facebook, authentication, facebook-authentication, passport.js

On the callback from Facebook for nodejs passport authentication, how do you get the `req` object within the callback?

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: 123456789,
    clientSecret: 'SECRET',
    callbackURL: "http://example.com/login/facebook/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){
    // Is there any way to get the req object in here?
  }
));
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Setting the [`passReqToCallback`](http://passportjs.org/docs#association-in-verify-callback) option, as so:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ passReqToCallback: true },
  function(req, username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) {
        req.flash('error', 'Your password is too long');
        req.flash('error', 'Also, it is too short!!!');
        return done(null, false);
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

`req` becomes the first argument to the verify callback

As per https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/39

Comment: This also works for me with facebook authentication.

Comment: Thank you!!  This was a big help.

Answer (score 7):

I am answering it too late, but i think my solution is better and more conventional.
In the official documentation [here](http://passportjs.org/guide/authorize/). There is a section "**Association in Verify Callback**", in which it is mentioned that if we set the strategy's **passReqToCallback** option to **true**, this enables **req** and it will be passed as the first argument to the verify callback.

So my **FacebookStrategy** now looks like:

```
var User = require('../models/UserModel.js');
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

exports.facebookStrategy = new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: 'REPLACE_IT_WITH_CLIENT_ID',
        clientSecret: 'REPLACE_IT_WITH_CLIENT_SECRET',
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback',
        passReqToCallback: true
    },function(req,accessToken,refreshToken,profile,done){
        User.findOne({
                'facebook.id' : profile.id
            },function(err,user){
            if(err){
                done(err);
            }
            if(user){
                req.login(user,function(err){
                    if(err){
                        return next(err);
                    }
                    return done(null,user);
                });
            }else{
                var newUser = new User();
                newUser.facebook.id = profile.id;
                newUser.facebook.name = profile.displayName;
                newUser.facebook.token = profile.token;
                newUser.save(function(err){
                    if(err){
                        throw(err);
                    }
                    req.login(newUser,function(err){
                        if(err){
                            return next(err);
                        }
                        return done(null,newUser);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
);
```

In my code sample i have added some logic to save user info in DB and saving user details in session. I thought it might be helpful to people.

**req.user** gives the information of user stored in passport session.

Comment: Thank you!!  This was a big help.

Comment: Hey @Tyguy7 Any idea of how to get the res object here. i need to redirect the user to a certain page based on a condition. How would res.redirect() work here? TIA